# Laravel 7 Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5

When I trying upload image as profile,
and then I get that message Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

```
public function update_image(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2040',
        ]);
        
        $user = Auth::user();
        $imgName = $user->id.'_img'.time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        
        $request->image->storeAs('images', $imgName);
        
        $request->image = $imgName;
        $user->save();
        
        return back()
            ->with('sucess', 'You have successful upload!');
    }
```

How can I do it ?

> And my route

```
Route::post('profile/img', 'Api\UserController@update_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user is not logged in.
To prevent this error, you should check if user is logged in.

For example by using:

```
Auth::check();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check()) {
  // Your code
}
```